# mixed limit of ·$ x^{-y} $ whenever x tends to $ \infty $ and $y \to 0^{+} $

Tags: limits

what would be the 2-dimensional limit

$$ x^{-y}=A $$

$ x \to  \infty $ and $ y \to 0^{+} $

i have tried with my calculator and this says that the lmit approaches to 1 but i would like to have a plot or another opinions

the idea would be to plot $ -ylog(x) $ but i think this is 0 because the logarithm tends slower to $\infty$ but i do not know how to prove this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether $x$ and $y$ are dependent or independent. If they are independent, it depends on the order of the limits, i.e. (assuming $x,y > 0)$,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{y \to 0^+} x^{-y} = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 = 1$$
whereas
$$\lim_{y \to 0^+} \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{-y} = \lim_{y \to 0^+} 0 = 0$$
We can let $x^{-y}$ tend to any arbitrary positive value in $(0,1)$ if $x$ and $y$ are dependent, i.e., given any positive number $a \in (0,1)$, if we let $y =-\ln_x(a)$. Then as $x \to \infty$ and $y \to 0^+$, we have $x^{-y} \to a$.

Comment: Would substituting $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ be a valid argument? Just wondering, since $y\to0^+$ means $\dfrac{1}{x}\to\infty$, so we evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^{1/x}$.

Comment: Yes, that would be taking the limit, as x goes to infinity and y goes to 0, along the curve y= 1/x.  While taking the limit along a single curve will not prove the limit, it is enough to show that the limit does not exist.